# Returning unique path types in neo4j in a graoh created by py2neo

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have created a graph database using py2neo in python3. I create relationships using the following code:

```
from py2neo import Graph,Node,Relationship

G=Graph()

node0=Node('Female',memberid=1234)
node1=Node('Male',memberid=3456)
node0_node1=Relationship(node0,'matched',node1)
node1_node0=Relationship(node1,'matched',node0)

G.merge(node0_node1)
G.merge(node1_node0)


node2=Node('Female',memberid=1357)
node3=Node('Male',memberid=3456)
node2_node3=Relationship(node2,'swiped_on',node3)

G.merge(node2_node3)
```

Problem 1:
I want to return *only* the paths where male points to female, I tried:

```
match (m:Male)-->(f:Female) return m,f
```

I only want (1234)<--(3456)-->(1357), but instead get:

[image: results of previous cypher query]

I then want to only return paths where a female swiped on a male, I tried:

```
match (f:Female)-[:swiped_on]->(m:Male) return m,f
```

I only wanted (1357)-[swiped_on]->(3456), instead I got:

[image: even though I specidied 'swiped_on' as the relationship, 'matched' is being returned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running this in the browser. When viewing the graph results, there's a control that says Auto-Complete, and it's currently set to ON. When it's on, the graph result will query and show all other relationships between returned nodes, even if they weren't part of the original query. To see only what was matched by your query, turn auto complete off.

Comment: you could literally knock me down with a feather right now! Many thanks!